# Как узнать включен ли мобильный интернет если включен wifi(с интернетом)?

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

Бьюсь над таким вопросом: Как узнать что мобильный интернет включен если wifi тоже включен и имеет интернет? И возможно ли вообще это сделать без выключения wifi или без ситуации когда wifi не будет иметь интернет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости ответ никак. Так как есть возможность только проверять к какому интернету подключен(или подключаешся) к мобильному или wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки состояния подлючения нужно использовать `NetworkInfo`.
Пример:

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
...
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

Просто напишите ваше логическое условие=)
Также [документация](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) в помощь.

Comment: Спасибо. Но я так уже пробывал и если включен wifi и мобильный интернет, то 
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
пишет false